# Like Box coming up as a blank screen or Like Button part only?

Tags: facebook-likebox

I want to put Like Box on a friend's site for him, but when I use the iframe code and then preview it, it comes up with only the Like Button part of Like Box.  When I use the html5 code and then preview in browser, all I get is a blank screen.  I tried going through previous questions here and found a few tips (modify &amp to &, etc.) but I still can't get it to work.  Also, most of the help I'm seeing has been for Wordpress and I'm not using that.  Does Like Box require MySQL or *_*?  Thanks for any help you can provide!

**TEST PAGE FOR iframe CODE:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>try</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
</head>

<body>
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FJaytamangPhotography&;width=520&;height=558&;show_faces=true&;colorscheme=dark&;stream=true&;border_color=black&;header=false" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:520px; height:558px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

**TEST PAGE FOR HTML5:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>try</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
</head>

<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/JaytamangPhotography" data-width="520" data-height="460" data-show-faces="true" data-colorscheme="dark" data-stream="true" data-border-color="black" data-header="false"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your iframe src URL is nonsense, because you put `&;` in there in every place where it should be just `&` (resp. `&amp;` when written in HTML).

And the HTML5 version does nothing, because you don’t initialize the JS SDK properly. (Need an app id.)

Comment: http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FJaytamangPhotography&width=520&height=558&show_faces=true&colorscheme=dark&stream=true&border_color=black&header=false called directly shows the like box perfectly fine for me. If it doesn’t for you, then you’re most likely still doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Test to see whether it works when you are both logged in and out of Facebook.  If it works when you are logged in but displays blank while logged out, there is probably a demographic restriction on the Facebook page.  (ex: "only display this page to users in the USA" or "only show page to ages 18+")  When a user is logged out, Facebook doesn't have any demographic info on them and so by default they won't display anything about the page.